# Adding an object to List View

Tags: android, listview, object, arraylist

So far no luck. Been trying to add an object to my listview with no luck. After I add it should just out put the name of the assignment even though I set the object with other parameters such as grade and category. This is code is placed into a fragment java class that outputs the listview

```
private void populateListView(){
    TeamArrayList = new ArrayList<CourseWorkItem>();
    CourseWorkItem myItem = null;
    myItem.setName("First Assignment");
    myItem.setCategory("Homework");
    myItem.setGrade(60);

    TeamArrayList.add(myItem);

    //creates an adapter
    itemArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CourseWorkItem>(this,R.layout.individualview,TeamArrayList);
    ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.courseListXML);
    v.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you overriden the toString method of CourseWorkItem to display the name?

Comment: No I have not. I should just erase that line so it doesnt cause confusion

Comment: I have getters, setters and 1 constructor for the CourseWorkItem Class

Comment: I think you should use a custom adapter to display the items. Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Answer (score 0):

you are using  default array adapter then you should pass the value as String[] ,otherwise you should create a custom adapter for this

try this for  default array adapter

```
String[] strings=new String[]{"First Assignment","Second Assignment"}; 
    //creates an adapter
    itemArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CourseWorkItem>(this,R.layout.individualview,TeamArrayList);
    ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.courseListXML);
    v.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
```